# Github Security Alerts package already update

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, git, github

I Have a Github Security Alerts :

[image]

But when I look in my project I found `package-lock.json`

[image]

AND

[image]

How I'm suppose to delete the first one? and why I have 2 time the same package?

If I make `npm ls mem` console return :

```
`-- react-native@0.61.4
  +-- @react-native-community/cli@3.2.1
  | `-- metro@0.56.4
  |   `-- yargs@9.0.1
  |     `-- os-locale@2.1.0
  |       `-- mem@1.1.0 
  `-- @react-native-community/cli-platform-android@3.1.4
    `-- logkitty@0.6.1
      `-- yargs@12.0.5
        `-- os-locale@3.1.0
          `-- mem@4.3.0
```

So I have to update one of these package?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

In your case "mem" is a dependency of at least 2 dependencies of your project. These two dependencies need different version of the package "mem". For example

```
Package A ---> "mem@4.3.0"

Package B ---> "mem@1.1.0"
```

To fix this issue you need to update the package B which uses a deprecated version of "mem".

To find this package B I advise you to use the command `$ npm ls mem` to list all packages using "mem" & then update the deprecated packages.

#### Edit

From your npm ls result, your only option is to update @react-native-community/cli manually to the latest of version 4, because the latest release of version 3 isn't up to date concerning the dependencies.

`$ npm install @react-native-community/cli@4`

Comment: thanks, when I put ```npm ls mem``` console return one package with mem@1.1.0 and a second with mem@4.3.0; I will update my original post to show the structure, but I have to make ```npm update @react-native-community/cli``` ?

Comment: @samuel  I'll wait for your update to answer your question

Comment: I have updated my post, thanks for sharing your knowledge